# Calculate the product distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Original question was to calculate the $X$, $Y$ and $XY$ distribution, however I have already done the first two, so I am just going to post the question the way I have it. 
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
ye^{-xy-y} & \textrm{when $x>0,y>0$}\\
0 & \textrm{in other case}\\
\end{array} \right.
$$
I calculated both
$$
f_X(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{(x+1)^{2}} & \textrm{when $x>0$}\\
0 & \textrm{in other case}\\
\end{array} \right.
$$
$$
f_Y(y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
e^{-y} & \textrm{when $y>0$}\\
0 & \textrm{in other case}\\
\end{array} \right.
$$
Since x and  y are dependent, i think i can not use the formula given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution, can someone help?

Comment: Work directly with the CDF $P(XY\le t)$ or use a change of variables $(X,Y)\to (XY,X)$ (say).

Answer (score -1):

If we assume that $XY=Z$, then $X=Z/Y$, and $f_Z(z)=0,\ \forall z\le0$.

For $z>0$: $$\begin{align}f_Z(z)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(z/y,y)\frac{1}{|y|}dy\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-z-y}dy\\
&=e^{-z}
\end{align}$$